# Synchronze on method call Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question about a block of code I am trying to understand

```
synchronized(Name.getname())
{
   Name.getname().add(this);
}
```

What does this block of code synchronize on? does it synchronize on the method call result or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is synchronized.
You used Name.getname() as a lock object.
If one thread acquires the Name.getname() object then other thread will wait until releasing object

Answer (score 2):

It synchronizes on the object returned by `Name.getname()`.

Just like `System.out.println(Name.getname())` prints the value returned by `Name.getname()`.

Everywhere you use an Object, an expression of type Object can be used.

Comment: I suspected that, what tripping me up is what it means for the object returned by Name.getname() to be used as the lock object. Can you shed more light on this? Thanks

Comment: I don't think anyone can shed light on that.  There's far too little information here.  I don't even know what the "Name" object is or does, let alone how it's used by the rest of the system.

Answer (score 1):

The (reference) value that is returned by `getname()` in the `Name` instance (or the static method if it isn't an instance) is used as the lock object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not adding any information that you can't find in the other answers, but sometimes a picture helps.

I'm guessing that `Name.getName()` returns a reference to a singleton Name instance.  If that's true, then your example is equivalent to this:

```
Name n = Name.getName();
synchronized(n) {
    n.add(this);
}
```

It seems strange to me that something called "Name" would be a singleton, and it seems strange to me that you would be allowed to add `this` to something called "Name", but I can't make any sense of your example at all unless `Name.getName()` always returns the same object reference.